# Absolute Path of Php Files on server

Tags: php, file, path, absolute

I've uploaded my PHP project to a server. It worked perfectly on localhost, but when accessed online some CSS paths do not work correctly.

It shows server path:

```
 /home/projectfolder/public_html
```

My files stored under Public_html folder as below.

```
index.php
about.php
gallery/product/gallery.php
contact.php
custom/css/bootstrap.css
custom/css/nav.css
custom/css/style.css
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: yes.. css files path not work.. all site content display but not aligned.

Comment: Case matters; what are the exact (except for obfuscation) paths here?

Comment: Can you please show your code? You might be using absolute path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give path like this for php file,

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/path/";
```

and for css file,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ?>/dist/css/tab.css"/>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ?>/dist/css/tab.css"/> for css do like this